# iOS app store submission - including a screenshot that isn't a screenshot of the app

Tags: ios-appstore, screen-capture, sms

Along with the screenshots of my app, I'd like to include a screenshot that shows what my app delivers e.g. an SMS message (picture is just for reference):

[image: SMS App]

One of the features of the app is to send SMS messages in a specific format, and I'd like to show this by including a screenshot of the iOS messaging app. - By doing this, would I risk getting rejected from the app store?

Comment: Hard to say but some "screenshot" in the store aren't screenshots at all. So at first glance you should be ok. Maybe you can label the picture with "Sample result" or similar.

Comment: "closed as off topic", and a down vote. Amazing help mods, pernickety infact, I'll come back when I have a question about memory or dead pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always a risk of rejection of an App store submission for not strictly following the guidelines.  Best to check what other popular apps display (some have variations that are not exactly screen shots, but photoshopped artwork similar to such) to see what they get away with.  But realize that Apple's previous approval of these apps does not set any precedent for continuing to do so.

You could try putting a help screen in your app, and display a smaller image of the SMS messages window within your own help screen.  They you really would be submitting a real screenshot of just your app.